# how can we improve documentation of project

Tags: project-management, documentation, requirements

We are planning to develop a database api for our project. I want to know how can we improve our documentation.

The Current Structure of a document is :

```
Introduction :
Database Objects :List
Each Object (Table) Field List
List of Common Input Parameters.
loop of each command of database api
   Input Parameter of command 
   Output Parameter of command 
   Example of using the command 
End of loop
```

Please suggest if we can improve our documentation. :)

Comment: I'll mention that StackOverflow.com has a bunch of questions on API documentation (just so a search) and on specific toosl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your document's structure it does seem you need a code-documenting tool like Doxygen, which will carry out the structure you're using by itself. It can handle long paragraphs alongside API comments, like Javadoc, as well.

To write documentation out of code, like manuals and the like, there's [LaTex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) and DocBook. I never used the latter, but [some people](http://wiki.docbook.org/WhoUsesDocBook) do. 
It's XML-based, you need an XML editor and the DocBook distribution to be installed, alongside with the templates for your documents. [Here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdp-handbook/stable/gettingstarted.html.en) GNOME people give a few instructions on how to get started with it. You may even find their templates useful for your projects.

LaTex instead is older and uses its own markup language, which tends to be less verbose than DocBook, and it's been used for a lot of time by a lot of people, so you have gazillions of resources. Check the Wikibook for it, it's quite good.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to document the database structure itself or the API that you are planning to create?

If it is the API documentation, then look into [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org). It's definitely a good tool to have.

Comment: both , is doxgen is also useful for the api we are planning to create ?